# How to Convert the Unicode into required format?

Tags: iphone

I Need Some Guide from u. i need convert the Unknown format unicode to My required format(tamil)

" ிய"  This is the format from URL , i need convert into Orinal Format..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is correct because I'm not sure whether your post is encoded accurately to represent your question...is your data in the format `\u0BBF\u0BAF`?

if so, this should work:

```
NSString *unicodeString = yourString;
const char *convert = [unicodeString UTF8String];
NSString *resultingString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:convert];
```

Comment: &#2970;&#3014;&#2985;&#3021;&#2985;&#3016; &#2986;&#3015;&#2999;&#2985;&#3021; &#2999;&#3019; 2011
thats my unicode from url...